# Plesk Migration failure

Tags: linux, plesk

When using plesk migration manager all content domains and databases seem to be copied to their places but when I log in to plesk I cannot see them. when I try to add them manually it says "domain already exists".

I assume that the domains were assigned to a user which is not visible and now i cannot access them through the control panel. Is there a file or something where i can edit this?

Comment: What version of Plesk are you using?  Are you logging in as "admin" or as another user?

Comment: Contact with your hosting provider helpdesk, I think is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you are suing Plesk on the windows server, try to do the following via remote desktop:

"%plesk_bin%\ftpmng.exe --remove-vhost -vhost-name=domain.com
"%plesk_bin%\ftpmng.exe --reconfigure-vhost -vhost-name=domain.com

Thus , your domain will get deleted from the server configuration and will be added buy the second command to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Plesk 11? The domains are now listed as 'Subscriptions'.

Next step, try running: /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all

When you're done, restart all plesk services. 
~# /etc/init.d/psa stop
~# /etc/init.d/psa start